# Changing content on different pages

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a beginner and I am making simple bilingual website with five pages from strach. The idea is to create one external js file with three functions for three diff. languages. In each function jQuery changing lang of all p and h elements in whole page. The default language-function  is called in body onload. Functions are called when flag is clicked. This works great on one page only.

How can I make system in which where user click flag the language change in whole site (all pages) until user click flag (change lang) again?

Thanks!

Comment: Cookies, localstorage, (webdis). Won't work without one of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not only one way the simplest way to use `localstorage` simply when body loads read the property lang in localstorage like

```
localStorage.getItem("lang")
```

and set everything according to this and when a flag is clicked simply update the localstorage entry

```
localStorage.setItem("lang","newLang")
```

and update the current page

if local storage is not supported you can think cookies which will work pretty the same but you shouldnt use if not needed because cookues are sent over  internet to the server which means if you dont wanna reach this info on server it is just waste of bandwith

last thing you can do if neither of previous methods are supported to add a querystring or hash after your links to change page

Comment: Problem solved, localStorage works perfect for me! Thanks for advice!

Comment: @Vlaya as we are working on remote machines with js on individual users computar u can never be sure that will work for ever thats Why consider to check all the possibilities may be the users browser is ancient or localstorage is blocked and you should check whether user runs browser in incognito mode in that case u should use the link trick a told above